# How to provide data-bind as string or javascript object?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a "options" binding dropdown that looks like the following:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: baseViewModel.filtersViewModel, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsText: function(self) { return self.Name }, value: baseViewModel.baseFilter(), optionsValue: 'Value', event: { change: function() { console.log('test'); applyFilter(baseViewModel.baseFilter()); return true; } }">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="{'sort':[]}">water group</option>
</select>
```

I am using this binding in various places in my application, is there anyway to declare the entire contents of the data-bind="***contents***" and pass it in (inject?) as a string or a javascript object? I have examined [preprocessing bindings](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html), however, I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Comment: I would make the component reusable rather than passing parameters as a string . 
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

Comment: In event that I wanted to pass parameters as a string, and not use a component, would I be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, you can create a custom binding that just has a `preprocess` method that sets all of the other bindings. For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.filterBinding = {
    preprocess: function(value, name, addBinding) {
        addBinding('options', 'baseViewModel.filtersViewModel');
        addBinding('optionsCaption', '"Choose..."');
        addBinding('optionsText', 'function(self) { return self.Name }');
        // etc.
    }
}
```